# Animation on Android Toolbar Back Button

Tags: android, android-animation, android-toolbar

I have an activity which has a Toolbar which displays a back button.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_about"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        />
```

The back button is enabled like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_about);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//noinspection ConstantConditions
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

I call this activity from my main activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The Activity's parent is defined in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".AboutActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".EntryActivity" />
</activity>
```

So far everything works fine, except that the transition animation is wrong when using the back button in the Toolbar.

When I open the activity, it slides in from the right.

When I press the phone's physical back button it slides out to the right again. This is correct.

However when using the Toolbar back button it slides out to the left. This looks wrong. How can I change this, so it duplicates the behaviour of the physical back button?

Comment: Do you actually need to define the parent activity in the manifest? By this I mean, are you supporting lateral vs hierarchical navigation or are you able to open `AboutActivity` from anywhere other than `EntryActivity`?

Comment: Well, if I don't define the parent, the button does nothing at all. I only have those two activities so yes the activity can only be called from the other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you press the Actionbar Up button, `AppCompatActivity` detects this button press in its `onMenuItemSelected()` call, and invokes `onSupportNavigateUp()`. This method determines the "parent activity" `Intent` and uses that to navigate up. Because it's using an `Intent` to (re-)open the previous activity, it uses the same animation it would for opening a "new" screen.

Assuming you don't care about the particular niceties of the "Up Navigation" pattern (which it sounds like you do not, as comments have led me to believe you don't have lateral navigation and you can't get to your second activity from anywhere other than your first activity), you can side-step all of this built-in "up" behavior by overriding the `onSupportNavigateUp()` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

This will mean that pressing the Actionbar Up button always simply `finish()`es your activity, so (like I said before) you lose out on all the smart built-in "up" behavior... but you didn't want that anyway.

You could also handle the Actionbar Up button in `onOptionsItemSelected()`, but I prefer the other way since I think it's a little more obvious that you're hijacking the system's up behavior.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

With either of these in place, you can remove the "parent" definitions from your manifest, since now they're not used.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. It didn't occur to me that onOptionsItemSelected() would be even related, but it makes since the toolbar is supposed to handle the menu, too. But you're right the onSupportNavigateUp() override is completely sufficient for my use case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
     onBackPressed()
     return true
 }`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default `launchMode` of activities is `standard`.
The documentation of `standard` states the following:

> The system always creates a new instance of the activity in the target task and routes the intent to it.

You can solve this by using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` on the parent/starting activity.

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity.

For more information see [Tasks and the back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) and [android:launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode).